# Resnet50 strange output size

Tags: python, keras, resnet

I used the following function:

```
def extract_resnet(X):
    resnet_model = ResNet50(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights=RESNET_WEIGHTS_PATH, include_top=False)
    features_array = resnet_model.predict(X)
    return features_array
```

And I used this function with my training data `X_train` of dimension: (24, 224, 224, 3), that is 24 images (224x224) pixel x 3 channels.

When I used:

```
X_train = extract_resnet(X_train)
```

the output is (24, 7, 7, 2048) but I expected something like (24,N), where N are the number of features obtained by `Resnet`.

Can somebody explain me if it is correct and what exactly are the (7, 7, 2048) features I have?
Once I obtained the features I have to train them.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should  probably set include_top to True.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I need to exclude the top layer, in fact if I use include_top to True, I obtain:  ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 106 layers into a model with 107 layers.

Comment: Okay, if you exclude the top layer you need to make a classifier yourself. Now you have an output of size (7,7,2048) you could flatten this and put into a linear layer of input size (7x7x2048) and output size the number of classes you have. This layer should be trained by you but you don't need a lot of data for this. If (7x7x2048) is too large to fit in your memory try to lower the dimension (for example take the average across the 7x7 dimension, then you only have 2048 dimesions left).

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestion. The point is (7,7,2048) is correct? So I have to reshape for example with the command: np.reshape(X_train, (len(X_train),100352))? Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes I think something like that would work. Then you can do whatever you want with that feature vector.

Comment: OK thank you very muh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239524/discussion-between-user3318590-and-areobe).